# How to get event.target.name from react onClick event for table header (th)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an *onClick* event in my table header which I am using for sorting the table. I need the table header html element name passed to my onclick handler.

A simplified version of the handler is shown below:

**html:**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th name='name' value='test' onClick=onClickhandler(event)> Click me </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**js:**

```
  onClickhandler = event => {
      console.log("Event target name = " + event.target.name);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vaf5sutn/4/

**Problem**

the above code returns as a log `Event target name = undefined`.

**Expected**

the console log should return `Event target name = name`

Comment: `th` does not have support `name` property unlike `input` tags. If you need a custom attribute, you can use `data-name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change from `event.target.name` to `event.target.getAttribute('name')`

```js
 onClickhandler = event => {
    console.log("Event target name = " + event.target.getAttribute('name'));
  }
```

```html
 <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th name='name' value='test' onClick=onClickhandler(event)>Click me</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: personally, I would avoid setting randomly named attributes on elements. While `name` is a valid attribute, it's only valid for a subset of node types, TH **not** being one of them

Comment: this works! Thank you. I didn't realize this was an issue with TH not supporting "name" attribute. Is there a recommended way to reference this element for the purposes of running a function for sorting a column i.e. I was using "name" to let my function know which attribute of the object model to sort by? should I be using "id instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th name='name' value='test' onClick=onClickhandler(this)>Click me</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```